# Why pytest.mark.parametrize does not work with classes in pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Following code does not collect any test cases (i expect 4 to be found). Why?

```
import pytest
import uuid

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
            command_executor='http://my-selenium:4444/wd/hub'
        )

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [1,2,3,4])    
    def test_buybuttons(self, data):
        self.browser.get('http://example.com/' + data)
        assert '<noindex>' not in self.browser.page_source

    def __del__(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

If i remove `__init__` and `__del__` methods, it will collect tests correctly. But how i can setup and tear test down? :/

Answer (score 6):

`pytest` won't collect test classes with an `__init__` method, a more detailed explanation of why is that can be found here: [py.test skips test class if constructor is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430900/py-test-skips-test-class-if-constructor-is-defined).

You should use [fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) to define setup and tear down operations, as they are more powerful and flexible.

If you have existing tests that already have setup/tear-down methods and want to convert them to pytest, this is one straightforward approach:

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_browser(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
            command_executor='http://my-selenium:4444/wd/hub'
        )
        yield  # everything after 'yield' is executed on tear-down
        self.browser.quit()


    @pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [1,2,3,4])    
    def test_buybuttons(self, data):
        self.browser.get('http://example.com/' + data)
        assert '<noindex>' not in self.browser.page_source
```

More details can be found here: [autouse fixtures and accessing other fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html#autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures)