# pytest run tests inside a class with a constructor

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I want to write a test suite for an API. my project tree looks like:
[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q994.png)

I need to have a 'client' file with classes where we initialize all the helper functions(e.g. the actual request that is sent with the params, asserts, configs etc.). And the actual test class. so I have

```
class Client()
  __init__()
  def helper_function()
class TestBackend(Client)
  __init__()
  def test_something()
```

Then I try to run my tests with pytest. I keep getting

> PytestWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestBackend' because it has
>   a **init** constructor.

As described by [py.test skips test class if constructor is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430900/py-test-skips-test-class-if-constructor-is-defined) this is the expected behavior. the SO links to this [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)
but for the love of all that is holy I'm unable to find the solution to the issue I'm having and I don't believe it's not a case that is frequently required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, if  `__init__()` is defined in the class, then the `py-test` would not collect the classes for the testing purpose. But, if you want to initialize all the helper methods and file, then you could add that file in the pythonpaths in `pytest.ini` configuration file like below:-

```
[pytest]
python_paths = . <path to helper file>
```

And from then, you could directly import that particular file in your test script.

Comment: This is definitely a fix for the issue - but I can't believe this is considered a good coding practice. This would be a nightmare to maintain and debug!

Comment: Also where would i instantiate my helper class?

Comment: Actually, ini file is used to alter the default configuration of the pytest module. And you could create an object of the class in test script of fixture itself.
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

Comment: Actually what i missed was that the Suite should inherit from unittest.TestCase for all of this to work. Thank you Nikilesh for your time:)